# How to also get the name of the city when geocoding?

Tags: mapbox, geocoding

I am using the [Mapbox Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#geocoding) to find the latitude and longitude of a place provided by user input. This works great. I would also like to display the name of the city which is at this location.

This is an example request, which searches for "70176", a postcode in Germany:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/70176.json?fuzzyMatch=true&language=en&access_token=redacted
```

This is the answer:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "query":[
      "70176"
   ],
   "features":[
      {
         "id":"postcode.12480061547829920",
         "type":"Feature",
         "place_type":[
            "postcode"
         ],
         "relevance":1,
         "properties":{

         },
         "text_en":"70176",
         "place_name_en":"70176, Stuttgart, Baden-Württemberg, Germany",
         "text":"70176",
         "place_name":"70176, Stuttgart, Baden-Württemberg, Germany",

   [...]

}
```

As you can see it does provide the full address which includes the city ("Stuttgart") but it is not separated. You can specify that you are only looking for cities by including `&types=place` in your query but then it will only accept city names as input as well.

How can I get latitude, longitude and the name of the city without making two API calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually get all this information from the request you made:

The coordinates of the center of the bounding box, boxing the city are returned in the "center" item of the features JSON object. The city name you get from the "place_name" item of the features object. You would have to parse the string and split it by comma, then select the second item of the returned array to get the city name.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"query": [
    "70176"
],
"features": [
    {
        "id": "postcode.12480061547829920",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "postcode"
        ],
        "relevance": 1,
        "properties": {},
        "text_en": "70176",
        "place_name_en": "70176, Stuttgart, Baden-Württemberg, Germany",
        "text": "70176",
        "place_name": "70176, Stuttgart, Baden-Württemberg, Germany",
        "bbox": [
            9.155781,
            48.77099,
            9.169018,
            48.784448
        ],
        "center": [
            9.16,
            48.78
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                9.16,
                48.78
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "place.5443458428087800",
                "wikidata": "Q1022",
                "text_en": "Stuttgart",
                "language_en": "en",
                "text": "Stuttgart",
                "language": "en"
            },
            {
                "id": "region.10788925313210430",
                "short_code": "DE-BW",
                "wikidata": "Q985",
                "text_en": "Baden-Württemberg",
                "language_en": "en",
                "text": "Baden-Württemberg",
                "language": "en"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.10743216036480410",
                "short_code": "de",
                "wikidata": "Q183",
                "text_en": "Germany",
                "language_en": "en",
                "text": "Germany",
                "language": "en"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: If it only were that easy... depending on the query the name of the city sometimes is the first or third thing in place_name.

Comment: How about using "text_en" of the "context" child JSON object, where "id" starts with place? This is appears to be unique.

Comment: I also tried that but it is the same. The city is not always the first context child.

Comment: That does not matter, which position it is. Just loop through the context JSON objects and look for the object that has the "id" value start with "place".

Comment: Great idea! Unfortunately, it doesn't always exist. Try for example "Moscow".

Comment: I ended up with `city: data.features[0].place_type[0] === "place" ? data.features[0].text : data.features[0].context.find(c => c.id.includes("place")).text` and it seems to work great. Thank you very much. In case you want to check it out: https://thewthr.app.